# Speeding up time flow for stability testing

Tags: linux, time, testing

Is it possible to speed up time flow in Linux system? Doesn't matter if virtualized or on bare metal. I need to test if my program could have uptime for ~10 years. So accelerating about 4000 times of the normal flow is necessary. Performance isn't my concern, since the program does most of the time nothing and waits for very sporadic inputs.

Comment: I am very dubious about how realistic such a test would be. With the exception of the millenium bug (and the Unix 32-bit millenium bug) I cannot imagine a scenario where uptime alone might impact behaviour. Also, the cases where a program would run on the same hardware without power cycles, kernel patching or dependency patching are rare. (I expect someone will point out space travel - but restarts are advisable to mitigate cosmic radiation effects).

Comment: @symcbean in the embedded world it’s not that unusual to have programs running for years with no restarts (*e.g.* battery-backed disconnected control systems).

Comment: @symcbean I was more thinking about possible memory fragmentation, unexpected freezes and so on. The customer defines an uptime requirement, so I would like to reasonably test it.

Comment: These are consequences of other things happening. Not explicitly time. Making the system clock faster will not make the other things happen faster/more frequently.

Comment: @symcbean exactly, that's what I'm asking. If it's possible, accelerating the time, not just time-keeping. I'm imaging it like a turbo button on an old PC. The OS, would perceive normal time flow, but it will be faster. Like 300MHz guest machine running with 10x faster on 3GHz host CPU. Some virtualization shall do it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `date` to fast forward into the future. Make sure NTP or anything time syncing is **not** running.

Here are two other alternatives: https://superuser.com/questions/619848/can-i-speed-up-a-vm-to-emulate-the-passage-of-time

Answer (score 0):

For very small adjustments, that's the system call `adjtimex` does.
For these, you should *not* do things like simply setting the time into the future – that breaks things, and in fact will *not* increase the "perceived" passage of time, just introduce jumps.

However, using `adjtimex` you can only increase thing by around 10% (due to the minimum time that setting `timex.tick` allows for is 0.909… µs, instead of the nominal 1 µs).

Comment: @marcus-mueller AFAIK ```adjtimex``` allows just fine-tuning of the time, not speeding it up much beyond 1s per 1s

Comment: @LiborTomsik I had to read up on this, and you're right: the `timex.freq` field allows for a maximum value of 33554432, and that corresponds to 512 ppm – so, a frequency adjustment of barely 0.05 %. I thought you'd simply adjust `ADJ_TICK`, but you can only adjust that between ca 0.909… µs and 1.1… µs, so also just 10% pull range :/